# How can I translate the ASP.NET Report Viewer messages?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Is there a way to translate the ASP.NET Report Viewer messages, such as "Find", "Next", "Export" and so on.

I have a class to translate but it works only in Windows Forms version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your class implement `IReportViewerMessages`?  If so, it works with the web ReportViewer too. This MSDN page shows what you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportviewermessages(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

MSDN will get you on the right path. In addition, a list of all the original default values of IReportViewerMessages will assist you in creating an accurate translation. You may find such a listing in the following link:

http://devillers.nl/localizing-microsoft-reportviewer/

The post provides a complete table of all the original values and an example implementation in Dutch complete with unit tests.